# Ng-include losing scope

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-include

I need to show different forms depending on user clicking different buttons. The user should be able to switch different forms and read previous data inserted. Unfortunately it seems like ng-include does not preserve scope but refresh data shown.

code:

```
...
<div ng-include src="formToBeOpened.urlForm"></div>
...
```

`formToBeOpened` change on user click on different buttons and `.urlForm` is a string    (e.g. "option1.html", "option2.html")

How to preserve data with ng-include?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following solution

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.templateUrl = 'form1.html';
  $scope.changeForm = function(url){
   $scope.templateUrl = url;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="form1.html">
            <h2>Hello1</h2>
        </script>

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="form2.html">
            <h2>Hello2</h2>
        </script>
        
        <div ng-include="templateUrl"></div>
        <button ng-click="changeForm('form1.html')">Form1</button>
        <button ng-click="changeForm('form2.html')">Form2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this is help you.